# Writing into the file and reading the contents of same file in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to writing into the file and reading the content from the file, I able to write into the file but I unable to read the contents from the file.

Tried Code:

```
-module(main).
-export([file_wr/1,file_wrt/2,file_rede/2]).

file_wr(Str) ->
  {ok,File} = file:open("input.txt",[write]),
  D = [[D] || D <- Str],
  file_wrt(File,D),
  file_rede(File,D),
  file:closeall(). 
file_wrt(File,[]) ->
    File;
file_wrt(File,[First | Last]) ->
 io:fwrite(File, "~s",[First]),
 file_wrt(File,Last).
file_rede(File,[]) -> 
  file:close(File),
  io:fwrite("\nCompleted\n");
file_rede(File,D) ->
  {ok,List} = file:open(File,[read]),
  {ok,Read} = file:read(List,1024*1024),
   case io:read(Read,"") of 
     eof ->
          file:close(File), D;
     Item ->
          file_rede(File,D ++ [Item])
    end.
```

And I modified the above code to the below mentioned that will writing/reading the contents into/from the file. To achieve this, I written the two modules (), the reading module is imported into the written module in the below code.

Code for Reading the Contents from the file:

```
-module(file_reading).
-export([reading/1,readlines/1,get_all_lines/2]).
reading(FileName) ->
 Lines =readlines(FileName),
 io:format("~s~n",[Lines]).
readlines(FileName) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
    get_all_lines(Device, []).
get_all_lines(Device, Accum) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, " ") of
        eof  -> file:close(Device), Accum;
        Line -> get_all_lines(Device, Accum ++ [Line])
    end.
```

The above module is import into the writing module , it will be executing in single module for both writing and reading from the single file.

Code for Writing and reading the contents from the file:

**

```
-module(file_writing).
-export([start/1,file_wrt/2]).
-import(file_reading,[reading/1]). #Importing the reading from the file_reading module and I defined in the same main branch.
start(FileName) ->
 io:format("~nReading the contents to the given file line by line: ~s ~n",[FileName]),
 String = io:get_line("Enter a string: "),
 L = [[L] || L <- String ],
 file_wrt(FileName,L),
 file:close(FileName),
 io:format("~nPrinting the contents of the given file: ~s ~n ",[FileName]),
 file_reading:reading(FileName).
file_wrt(FileName,L) ->
 {ok, S} = file:open(FileName, [write,append]),
   lists:foreach(fun(X) -> io:fwrite(S, "~s",[X]) end, L),
    
    file:close(S).
```

**

Comment: How are you running this code? What is the error you see?

Comment: I will give the a sequence of words like sentence as input in file_wr("sentence"), and its write into the given file i.e.., input.txt and i am trying to print the contents in the written file in the prompt by calling the file_rede(File,D) function/module, but its not printing on the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails because you pass data where an I/O device is expected.

1. In your `file_rede/2` function, you first call [`file:open/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) which for success returns `{ok, IoDevice}`. The `IoDevice` variable is like a [file descriptor or file handle](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#type-device). In your code, your I/O device variable is named `List`.
2. You then correctly pass `List` as the first argument to [`file:read/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read-2), which for success returns `{ok, Data}` where `Data` is the data read from the file. In your code, your data variable is named `Read`.
3. But in the next step, you call [`io:read/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#read-2) passing `Read` as the first argument, where `io:read/2` expects an I/O device as the first argument. This causes an exception.

Note that `io:read/2` reads an Erlang term from its I/O device argument, first displaying its second argument as a prompt. Unfortunately, it's not clear from your question why you're calling this.